# Display temporary table in PHP - MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

need some help.
We are processing data and storing it in a temporary variable @TEMP.

Storing it in a procedure, we want to display the @TEMP table on our PHP website. 
We are using PDO for database connectivity.

We are able to display data from database tables, but I want to display @TEMP table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowReport
@Username
AS
BEGIN
/*...
INSERT INTO @TEMP ()...

UPDATE @TEMP SET .....
*/ 

SELECT * FROM @TEMP
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used PHP, but the only difference between a procedure that selects directly from tables, and one that loads a temp table or table variable first, and then selects from that is the rowcount messages.   Some drivers stop looking for resultsets when they get a rowcount message from the database server.

So try to SET NOCOUNT ON in the beginning of your procedure.  EG

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowReport
@Username
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
/*...
INSERT INTO @TEMP ()...

UPDATE @TEMP SET .....
*/ 

SELECT * FROM @TEMP;
END
```

Comment: It did give an error related to something you just explained. Ill try it and let you know if it worked!

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` should be the first line of code in any stored procedure